# How to use Admin Model as foreign key in django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-admin

I try to develop a relationship as
One admin can add one or many subscription plans.

I try this but not worked

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib import admin

class SubscriptionPlansModel(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    price = models.IntegerField()
    duraion = models.IntegerField()
    admin = models.ForeignKey(admin,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Answer (score 1):

you literally making a ForeignKey relation with a module not a db model

Comment: Okk but what is the actual location of the Admin Model. How can I import it?

Answer (score 0):

Just create "Admin" class in models file. Then, use it as foreign key.

E.g.

```
class Admin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    pass

class SubscriptionPlansModel(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    price = models.IntegerField()
    duraion = models.IntegerField()
    admin = models.ForeignKey(admin,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```